# Creating a counter php

Tags: php, while-loop, counter

I would like to make a while loop which executes and echos out the values between 1 and 90, each being 1 second apart.  However, instead of them all being written in a row, I'd just like it to increase the one echoed value, if that makes sense.  It's supposed to be for a football game and is basically a timer.  I am not too sure on how to do it so any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: PHP can't do this without reloading the page. Javascript can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will hang the PHP engine for a minute and a half if you use PHP for the counter. The result that is shown to the user is a page with the number 90 that took 90 seconds to load. What you need is javascript to increase the values of a text span after a second.

In PHP, echo just the first number, and use JS to increment every second.

```
<?php
echo '<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function advance() {
            var txt = parseInt(document.getElementById("timertext").innerHTML);
            document.getElementById("timertext").innerHTML = txt + 1;
            if(txt != 89) {
                setTimeout("advance()", 1000);
            }
        }
    </script>
<head>
<body onload="advance()">
    <span id="timertext">1</span>
</body>';
?>
```

Comment: This seems like a more than logical working, although I'm confused as at the moment.  There are 2 things:

Comment: (1) - Whatever txt is, it adds 1 to the end of it, as though it is a string.  I tried turning it into an int, although that stops any addition of one occurring, so how do I go about fixing that?  And also, how do I set the upper limit of 90 seconds for this to be happening?

Thanks for your help so far, much appreciated

Comment: @BateWes Ah, well, I don't use javascript every day so I couldn't remember the effect of using a + operator between a numeric string and a number (unfortunately it seems that it doesn't have the desired effect). For question 2, I had forgotten to limit it when the number reaches 90. I edited the code above to reflect these changes.

Comment: I have managed to make it work, forgot to update you upon that situation, thanks very much for your help sir!